# Unix "at" command: I don't want it saving output to /var/mail/

Tags: unix, at

By default (and from what I've looked at thus far), `at` dumps the standard terminal text output to `/var/mail/yourusername`. (e.g. `echo "hello" | at now + 1 minute` will save a log about the command) Is there some way to disable this, or an argument I can pass in to keep it from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect your output to null

```
>/dev/null 2>&
```

For example:

```
echo "/path/myscript > /dev/null 2>&1" | at now
```

Answer (score 2):

`at` doesn't dump it to /var/mail/username, it emails it to the user.  If your local mail server is configured to store messages in /var/mail/username, then it delivers them there.  If you don't want them there, then configure your mail server differently.

Answer (score 0):

At least on Linux there is the -M option to not send any mails.